# Where can I download swistrack for ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone! I noticed that swistrack appears as one of the many stacks that uses roscpp however there's no wiki page, thus I have no idea where to download the source from.

Does anyone know where swistrack for ROS is hosted?

Best regards,

Gonçalo Cabrita

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42403/where-can-i-download-swistrack-for-ros?/) by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on ROS Answers with karma: 591 on 2012-08-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

using roslocate prints out this info:

```
$roslocate info swistrack
- svn:
    local-name: swistrack
    uri: http://ua-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/arrg/ua_experimental/swistrack
```

checking out the repo seems to have a non-standard makefile which downloads swistrack from a 3rd party repo and applies a ros-specific patch.

---

Originally posted by [dearl](https://answers.ros.org/users/2762/dearl/) with karma: 96 on 2012-08-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gonçalo Cabrita](https://answers.ros.org/users/83/gon%C3%A7alo-cabrita/) on 2012-08-28**:
Thx so much!!! Always learning, I was not aware of roslocate!!!